# JPA Foreign Key is Null

Tags: java, jpa

I am working on a web app and I am using JSF and JPA(EclipseLink). I have the tables `story` and `story_translate`, which are mapped as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "story")
public class Story{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Integer id;
private String title;
private String description;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "story", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<StoryTranslate> translateList;

    //getters and setters
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "story_translate")
public class StoryTranslate{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Integer id;
@Column(name="STORY_ID")
private Integer storyId;
    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="story_id", referencedColumnName="id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
private Story story;

   //some other fields, getters and setters
}
```

In a `ManagedBean` I am doing the following:

```
 StoryTranslate translate = new StoryTranslate(null, sessionController.getEntity().getId(), getAuthUser().getId(), language, 
                    title, description, new Date(), false);
 EntityTransaction transaction = TransactionSingleton.getActiveInstance();
            Story story = storyService.read(sessionController.getEntity().getId());
            if (story != null){
                if (story.getTranslateList() == null){
                    story.setTranslateList(new ArrayList<StoryTranslate>());
                }
                story.getTranslateList().add(translate);
                translate.setStory(story);
            }
            transaction.commit();
```

When I try to create a new `StoryTranslate`, I get a `DatabaseException`, saying the `story_id` cannot be null.

I have managed relationships before, but I have never seen this error.

Where is the problem?

**EDIT:** I am sorry, but I have forgotten about another part of the mapping(must be the lack of sleep).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your declare the `storyId` property in the  `StoryTranslate` class for the `STORY_ID` column  but when adding a new `StoryTranslate` , you do not set any value to its `storyId` property and I believe `STORY_ID` column has a NOT NULL constraint and that why you get the exception saying that story_id cannot be null.

The problem should be fixed once you set the `storyId` property of the `StoryTranslate` instance before committing the transaction .

But it is strange that you map the `STORY_ID` column to two different properties ( `storyId` and `story`) of the `StoryTranslate` class . Actually you  do not need to declare `storyId` property  as this value can be retrieved from the `story` instance . I suggest you change the  mapping of `StoryTranslate` to the following and your code should work fine without any changes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "story_translate")
public class StoryTranslate{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="story_id")
   private Story story;

   //some other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: What if my `parent class Story` table name is set as `@Table("my_story")`, how would I map the `@JoinColumn`? What's the naming convention here?